# AWS Cloud9 pip-3.6 を実行してもエラーになる

Tags: python3, aws, aws-lambda

アプリケーションフォルダ`~/environment/xx/xx`をカレントにし、

```
$ sudo pip-3.6 install requests -t .
```

を実行しました
パッケージはカレントに展開されました

```
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return ''
```

を作成し、最上段のメニュー右「Run」で実行すると、何もないですが動きます

```
Process exited with code: 0
```

`lambda_handler`から実行したいので「Lambda(local)」に切り替え、「/xx/.debug/xx/lambda_function.py」の左「Run」を実行するとエラーになります

```
Response
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'xx/lambda_function'"
}

Function Logs
Unable to import module 'xx/lambda_function': No module named 'requests'
```

pipのやり方が良くないと思うのですがどのようにすべきでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決したようです

```
$ venv/bin/pip3.6 install requests
```

APIGatwayにデプロイしていないのでその辺確認してた上で追記するようにします

追記：
デプロイは、問題なくできました